# Carousel - How do i select carousel item and open modal from the selection

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I am using react bootstrap and having carousel . Want to select carousel item and open modal from the selection   But unable to do so any help

Comment: share more information, code-snippets, etc.    The `react-modal` package is a good component to make use of for modals.

Comment: const MyCarousel2 = ({ items }) =>

  <div className="root">
    <Carousel controls={true} className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      {items && items.map((item, i) =>
        <Carousel.Item key={i}>
          <a className="thumbnail" href="javascript:handleSelect(item)">
            <img className="media-object" src={Constants.posterBasePath + item.poster_path} alt={item.title} />
          </a>
        </Carousel.Item>
      )}
    </Carousel>
  </div>;

Comment: Here my carousel is showing list of items i want to click on carousel take selected item property and open the modal bypassing the property

Comment: okay, i would wrap the Carousel.Item component in a new component with a click event and render that.  Ill spin up a mockup and post it when i get a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first wrap the `Carousel.Item` component and add a modal and click handler to the wrapped instance, something like the following maybe

```
class Item extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { caption, title, src, alt, className, modal } = this.props;

        return (
            <Carousel.Item>
                <img
                    className={className}
                    src={src}
                    alt={alt}
                    onClick={e => this.setState({ show: true })}
                />
                <Carousel.Caption>
                    <h1>
                        {title}
                    </h1>
                    <p>
                        {caption}
                    </p>
                </Carousel.Caption>

                {/* --> modal instance <-- */}
                <Modal
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onHide={() => this.setState({ show: false })}
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">
                            {modal.title}
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        {modal.content}
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ show: false })}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
                {/* --> end modal instance <-- */}
            </Carousel.Item>
        );
    }
}
```

next, I would use this in my `Carousel` component as follows

```
class MyCarousel extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            items: [
                {
                    caption: "blah 1",
                    title: "blah 1",
                    src: "/path/to/image",
                    alt: "blah 1"
                },
                {
                    caption: "blah 2",
                    title: "blah 2",
                    src: "/path/to/another/image",
                    alt: "blah 2"
                }
            ]
        };

        this.renderItems = this.renderItems.bind(this);
    }

    renderItems() {
        const { items } = this.state;

        items.map(item => {
            const modal = {
                title: item.title,
                content: item.caption
            };

            return <Item key={item.title} {...item} modal={modal} />;
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel>
                {this.renderItems()}
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i will try out

Comment: Yes . I modified my code now its working as expected . Thanks for help

Comment: no prob bro! feel free to hit that upvote button ;), happy coding!